# Google Calendar API. Handling sharedExtendedProperty for events

Tags: java, google-custom-search, google-calendar-api

Following [Google API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/extended-properties) I add custom properties for the specified user.
I've tried it - it works for me in general. I can add `String` properties and `String` values. Also I was successful with loading correspond data from Google if property value completely matched. Format to specify criteria for shared properties is (similar for private):

```
  /**
   * Extended properties constraint specified as propertyName=value. Matches only shared
   * properties. This parameter might be repeated multiple times to return events that match all
   * given constraints.
   */
  public List setSharedExtendedProperty(java.util.List<java.lang.String> sharedExtendedProperty) {
    this.sharedExtendedProperty = sharedExtendedProperty;
    return this;
  }
```

Right now I need have a collection in Google properties for `publicCase` property. And after that I should be able match one with correspond criteria request. Is it possible find in Google calendar events that contain `publicCase` custom property `where publicCase in ["valueCollection"]`? If Its possible please share for me correspond information.

Another question. Is it possible specify condition matching subSting of property value?

How I can specify `OR` rule in request? Is it possible?

### PS

As Google client I use `google-api-services-calendar-v3-rev225-1.22.0.jar`. I would be happy if any correct example (`java`, `js`, `pyton` and other) or API documentation that answers my questions.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't got perfect solution provided by Google, but I used workaround that uses functionality provided by Google.

If I can't use complex condition to match field value by `inRage` or `subValue` or else, solution is based on building *smart* field names. For example, I need add `crmCollection` field filled in by data, but Google API provides me to add `string` value only. I would convert the collection into *json* and I'd represent it as string in this way custom field would be added but I'll not be able to search any calendar events by it. So collection should be separated on single elements. It's easy to split it on single elements if elements can be named in different way. In current case it almost impossible and workaround is to add at the end of field name special marker (each data element has an unique field like `id` which can be used in custom field name building). In the very end using same rule I've got ability build search requests using each custom property:

```
Map <String, String> (key | value)
-----------------------------------
"crmCollection" | "[crmObject1, crmObject2, crmObject3 ...]" (in json representation)
```

transformed into:

```
Map <String, String> (key | value)
-----------------------------------
"crmCollectionIdOfFirstObject"  | "true"
"crmCollectionIdOfSecondObject" | "true"
"crmCollectionIdOfThirdObject"  | "true"
```

the real objects i have in my storage, but in Google I've specified links on my objects to be loaded by need.

### PS

I've considered a few other workarounds, but I've not published them because I think this one is the best of all of them. Anyway I open to consider other solutions (better ideas or missed Google API).